# SQL How to handle an exception in user defined functions?

Tags: sql, exception, user-defined-functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function fun_Find_Staff_Name( v_staffid IN NUMBER )
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
staff_name VARCHAR2(60);
CURSOR c_staff IS
  SELECT staff_firstName || ' ' ||  staff_lastName
  into staff_name
  FROM staff
  WHERE staff_id = v_staffid;
BEGIN
OPEN c_staff;
FETCH c_staff INTO staff_name;  
CLOSE c_staff;
RETURN staff_name;
END;
```

This function takes a staff_id and returns the corresponding staff name. I want to handle the exception if the user enters an ID that is invalid and display an error message? Where do I add the exception block?

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
v_staff_ID NUMBER := &StaffID;
v_message VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
v_message := fun_Find_Staff_Name(v_staff_ID);
dbms_output.put_line(v_message);
END;
```

I used this anonyomus block to check if the function works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you don't need an explicit cursor, an embedded sql will do the trick:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function fun_Find_Staff_Name
( v_staffid IN NUMBER ) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS 
staff_name VARCHAR2(60);
BEGIN
  SELECT staff_firstName || ' ' || staff_lastName 
       INTO staff_name 
     FROM staff WHERE staff_id = v_staffid; 
  RETURN staff_name;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  --in case of an invalid id no data will be found
  --you can treat your exception here
  --example
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found for this id: ' || v_staffid);
    RAISE;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END fun_Find_Staff_Name ;
```

And please remember that when you are handling exceptions don't forget to raise it; if not the database will not rollback the transaction in case of an error.

If it yells some errors at the compilation, I am sorry, but I wrote the code without compiling it (in a hurry from my mob).

Cheers and happy coding.